# Is Matplotlib the only plotting software compatible with Tkinter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, software-design

I want to create my own Gnome Power Statistics for my laptop and use Tkinter to switch between long term history view:

[image: battery long term.png]

and short term view:

[image: battery short term.png]

The difference is I will be collecting both more and less battery data points and providing more start/end times. Also it will power on/off the battery charger with a smart plug each Wednesday night.

After searching in Stack Overflow all roads seem to lead to Matplotlib using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Is this the only option or are there other open source libraries available to generate dynamic graphs as shown above?

I'm particularly attracted to software which has multiple questions and answers here in Stack Overflow which is $73,160 / yr. cheaper than MIT.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you have against the usage of `matplotlib`?

Comment: @HenryYik I just didn't want to go with my first choice without getting input from others who might know better.

Answer (score 2):

When looking at your provided images, it appears that the function plot you need is really basic: a background dashed grid (seems to be constant), a vertical scale (seems to be constant also), an horizontal scale (depending on the chosen period), and a bunch of line segments for the plot itself. This can be easily implemented in pure `tkinter` using the `Canvas` widget. You may give it a try...

**EDIT (after your comment) :** Here is a sample code that draws three curves (a damped cosine wave and its two damping bell-shape curves) on a dashed grid. I guess that it may be a good starting point, to understand the general process:

```
from tkinter import *

def draw_curve():
    from math import cos, exp
    w, h, colors = width//2, height//2, ('#0F0','#F00','#00F')
    for n in range(3): # loop over curves
        xa, ya, xb, yb = 0, h, 0, h # initial position for each curve
        for x in range(w+1): # loop over horizontal axis
            t = 2*x/w - 1 # parameter t moves over range [-1,1]
            if n == 2: # draw damped cosine wave
                xa, ya, xb, yb = xb, yb, 2*x, h + h*exp(-5*t*t)*cos(25*t)
            elif n == 1: # draw negative bell curve
                xa, ya, xb, yb = xb, yb, 2*x, h + h*exp(-5*t*t)
            elif n == 0: # draw positive bell curve
                xa, ya, xb, yb = xb, yb, 2*x, h - h*exp(-5*t*t)
            canvas.create_line(xa, ya, xb, yb, width=1, fill=colors[n])    

def draw_grid():
    steps = 20 # number of grid steps
    dw, dh = width/steps, height/steps # horizontal and vertical steps
    for n in range(steps):
        canvas.create_line(0, n*dh, width, n*dh, width=1, dash=(1,1)) 
        canvas.create_line(n*dw, 0, n*dw, height, width=1, dash=(1,1))
    canvas.create_rectangle(2, 2, width-1, height-1, width=1)

width, height = 800, 600
win = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(win, width=width, height=height)
canvas.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
draw_grid()
draw_curve()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: That's interesting is there a link you can provide on getting started with something similar to what I'm looking for by using plotting with Tkinter's (or tkinter's) Canvas class? I already use `tk.Canvas(....)` all over the place in my first Python program. Not having to use yet another tool would be a blessing.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix : I edited my post to add a sample code for drawing curves on Canvas